# Two different get_posts() returning same post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Wordpress and  trying to create some boxes retrieving information from Adanvec Customs Fields on a custom post type.

I have this code:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
    <?php
    $box1 = get_front_page_box("Box 1");
    $style_front = get_box_style($box1->ID, "front");
    echo $box1->ID;
    ?>
    <div id="front-box-1" class="front-box height-low <?php echo $box1->ID; if(has_back_panel($box1->ID)) echo "flip"; ?>">
        <div class="front" style="<?php echo $style_front; ?>"><a href="#">Banana</a></div>
        <?php
        if(has_back_panel($box1->ID)):
            $style_back = get_box_style($box1->ID, "back");
        ?>
        <div class="back" style="<?php echo $style_back; ?>"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5 hidden-xs">
    <?php
    $box2 = get_front_page_box("Box 2");
    $style_front = get_box_style($box2->ID, "front");
    echo $box2->ID;
    ?>
    <div id="front-box-2" class="front-box height-low <?php echo $box2->ID; if(has_back_panel($box2->ID)) echo "flip"; ?>">
        <div class="front" style="<?php echo $style_front; ?>"><a href="#">Banana</a></div>
        <?php
        if(has_back_panel($box2->ID)):
            $style_back = get_box_style($box2->ID, "back");
        ?>
        <div class="back" style="<?php echo $style_back; ?>"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And these functions:

```
function get_front_page_box($name) {
    $args = array(
        'post_title'   => $name,
        'post_type'    => 'front-page-box',
        'post_status'  => 'publish'
    );

    $box_array = get_posts($args);

    $box = $box_array ? $box_array[0] : false;

    print_array($box);
    return $box;
}

function get_box_style($id, $side) {
    $style = "";
    if(get_field($side."_panel_background_color", $id)) $style = "background-color:".get_field($side."_panel_background_color", $id).";";

    return $style;
}
```

But for some reason both boxes have the same details (both from Box 2).
Any idea why these are returning the same info? Both posts ("Box 1" and "Box 2" exist under the `front-page-box`custom post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the `post_title` is not a valid filter.
But found out there's a specific function to get posts by title.

[get_page_by_title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title)

Used `$box1 = get_page_by_title("Box 1", NULL, "front-page-box");`

Answer (score 0):

Just for check, if you add another Box named "Box 3", all boxes have results from "Box 2" or "Box 3" ?

Comment: Seems that the `'post_title'   => $name,` arguments is not being applied in the query.

Comment: Can you change "Box N" to "Box_N" and test it? Maybe error is whitespace

Comment: No, that was not the problem. Found the solution. Check my own answer above.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to use the post ID as the parameter in get_front_page_box().

Comment: I don't want to use the ID as people might delete the post and recreate it with the same name.